# Playing file video in device ionic framework 1

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm newbie using ionic framework. I want to play file video in device uses ionic.

ex: path file '../Library/NoCloud/Test/demo.mp4'

Please help me.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  can find different approaches if you google or visit ionic documentation...
Here i made a simple example with basic html video tag and js.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.makeAction=function(){

var vidURL = "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4";
var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
myVideo.src = vidURL;
myVideo.load();
myVideo.play();
}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <video  controls="controls" width="640" height="340" name="Video Name" ></video>
    <button type="button" ng-click="makeAction()">play</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks, but i want to play video file in locally not internet.

Comment: then make that file available in local and gave that video path to  vidURL

Comment: tag <video> cann't play file video in local.

Comment: I find other solution. Thank you for answering.

Comment: i find solution use plugin [link](https://github.com/nchutchind/cordova-plugin-streaming-media). You can try it. sorry for my bad english.